# Requirements for Creative Commons Images Attribution - Website

Tags: creative-commons

When I use a photo licensed under Creative Commons (from Flickr) on a website I make, what is the required way to give attribution?

Assuming the license allows commercial use and changes with attribution could I include the title, creator, and a tinyurl to the flickr image in a corner of my modified image? Or would that leave something out that I need to include?

If I need to include more information, are there more aesthetically pleasing ways to do this?

Answer (score 6):

You aren't required to include the attribution **on** the image, you can include it somewhere else on the page, placing it directly below the image is preferred, but providing it at the end of a post is acceptable.

[image]
<sup>Image Capture: [Attributing Creative Commons Materials](http://creativecommons.org.au/materials/attribution.pdf). [CC BY 2.5 Australia](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/au).</sup>

(↑ *See what I did there?*)

For best practices for providing attribution, see the Wiki: [Best practices for attribution](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/Best_practices_for_attribution).